# SSD lost size after erasing NTFS to HFS+

Tags: ssd

I bought SSD Samsung 850 Pro drive 
from my friend and it was NTFS formatted. I used macOS Disc Utility to erase it and after doing this the disc has 24 GB only (instead of 1TB). Any solution how to resize it to its previous capacity?

[image]
[image]

Comment: external usb case

Comment: OK, if the SSD is no fake, the only culprit left is the case/its USB and/or SATA controller. Do you have a second external case?

Comment: unfortunately don't have second one

Comment: Found a similar case [Samsung 850 Pro 1TB SSD only shows 22.4GB capacity???](https://hardforum.com/threads/samsung-850-pro-1tb-ssd-only-shows-22-4gb-capacity.1906404/) with 22.4 GiB (base 1024) = 24 GB (base 1000).

Comment: found second usb/sata case but nothing changed

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you didn't buy a 1 TB SSD but a 1 TB + 24 GB SSHD (a hybrid drive similar to Apple's Fusion Drives). At least 46949230 blocks à 512 Bytes amount to ~24 GB.

I haven't been able to find a model though (except for an SSHD option with the same sizes in some Dell laptops).

If the HDD part isn't visible at all, it's probably incompatible with macOS' disk framework.